# How to measure the error of a partial differential equation in the discrete norm?

Tags: numerical-methods

If we know the exact solution and approximate solution of a PDE then we can compute the error of both solutions in the discrete norm as given:
$\|u-u_N\|^2_M$ = $\frac{2\pi}{M}\sum _{j=0}^{M-1}(u(z_j, t)-u_N(z_j, t))^2$. I am unable to understand this relation... kindly explain.

Reference: it is written in the book Implementing Spectral Methods for Partial Differential Equations by David A. Kopriva

Comment: What is it you do not understand?

Comment: I am unable to understand the only equation mentioned above i.e $\|u-u_N\|^2_M$ = $\frac{2\pi}{M}\sum _{j=0}^{M-1}(u(z_j, t)-u_N(z_j, t))^2$

Comment: Well, if you define $\|f\|_M := \frac{2\pi}{M}\sum_{j=0}^{M-1}|f(z_j,t)|^2$ for a function $f : \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ then you get what's there, right? So, what's your point? The equation's interpretation?

Comment: in discrete fourier transform (DFT) why we set h =$ \frac { 2\pi}{M}$,  $z_j = jh=\frac{{ 2\pi}j}{M}$ and takes summation $\sum _{j=-M/2}^ {j= M/2-1}$ .